# Gif won't reset after it has been used

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, gif

I am trying to play a placing-animation using a .gif file, but weirdly it won't reset after I used it in an element. Is there an easy way to fix this issue?

```javascript
let particles = document.createElement("img");
particles.style = "left: "+(x)+"px; top: "+(y)+"px;";
particles.className = "tile";
document.body.appendChild(particles);
particles.src = "assets/gifs/place.gif";
setTimeout(function() {
   particles.remove()
}, 500)
```

I have tried to reset the image frame like preloading it, but nothing worked!

Answer (score 0):

## Debugging

### Does the `remove` work if you don't delay it?

i.e. What does this do?

```
    let particles = document.createElement("img");
    particles.style = "left: "+(x)+"px; top: "+(y)+"px;";
    particles.className = "tile";
    document.body.appendChild(particles);
    particles.src = "assets/gifs/place.gif";
    particles.remove()
```